# Windows Server 2008 R2 hangs when Editing folder permissions

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, domain

Background:

- The server in question is a member of a domain.
- This is a brand new server, freshly installed.
- I can log into this server using any domain user (which tells me that on some level it is accessing the DC and Active Directory).
- There are no local users (other than Administrator) on this server.
- `NET USERS /domain` returns all the users in the Active Directory.
- UAC is off (for now since I wasn't sure if this was the root of the problem).
- The following problem occurs whether I am logged in as the Local admin OR as the domain admin.

Problem:

All I want to do is change the permissions of a folder (and all sub items) to include one of my domain groups (the same problem occurs even if I just try to include a single user, or apply the permissions to a single file).

We have another server connected to the DC which is working perfectly. Changing file / folder permissions is generally a very simple task:

1. Right Click Folder (or file), and select Properties.
2. Under Security tab click Edit to change permissions.
3. Click Add to add the user or group.

And this is where my problem starts. The "From this location" field correctly displays my domain.

However, no matter what I type into the "enter object names to select" field, after clicking OK or Check Names a "Selection Progress" dialog box pops up with the content: "Objects Found: 0" and a Stop button. There is an icon indicating that the system is searching for more objects, but I can leave it for hours and it will not find anything. If I click Stop, nothing happens. Eventually, I have to force close.

Likewise, if I decide to click Locations the system will hang, and the "Select Users, Computers, Service Accounts, or Groups" dialog becomes unresponsive. The worst part is that out of the many times I have clicked on locations, one of them finally brought up the location dialog after around 30 minutes (so it's working on some level, but it's unbelievably slow). Of course, I clicked the little plus symbol next to the domain and it hung there indefinitely.

I am really at a loss here. This behavior seems related to Active Directory and my domain controller, but it doesn't make much sense since I can log in as domain user and validate within seconds.

Comment: eventvwr errors?  Specifically in System and Security...and for system even if it doesn't pertain directly to this issue/time.  For instance, any errors about Domain Controllers unavailable, etc?

Comment: I don't see anything of value there. In the Event Viewer tree, do I just expand Windows Logs and look at System, and Security there? Because I see nothing out of the ordinary in those.

Comment: I'm thinking there may be some communications issue between the server and the global catalog.  A few things, how many DCs are there?  If more than 1, can you check to see if there are any errors on those (in the event log)?  When was the server attached to the domain (wondering if maybe the computer password expired but there were still cached credentials)? Can you resolve the domain name from the server (nslookup yourdomain.local)?

Comment: Confused about something are you logged in locally via RDP when changing these permissions?

Comment: @tonyroth This actually occurred BOTH when logged in locally as local admin, and then via RDP as local admin OR domain admin.

Comment: use `DCDIAG` for replication/communication issues

Comment: @Snowburnt There is only 1 DC. nslookup seems to work (I get the expected results), and don't really see any valuable errors in the event viewer (I think you meant for me to check in the DC's event viewer). The server was attached yesterday.

Comment: What output do you get if you run `nltest /sc_verify:DOMAINNAME`? Have you considered turning on NTDS diagnostic logging?

Comment: @charleswj81 `Flags: b0 HAS_IP  HAS_TIMESERV` 
`Trusted DC Name \\MyDC.DOMAINNAME` 
`Trusted DC Connection Status Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success` 
`Trust Verification Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success` 
`The command completed successfully` I'm a novice at server administration, thus I don't anything about NTDS diagnostic logging. I will look into it however.

Comment: I'd like to add that I was able to "solve" this by simply waiting long enough. It literally took 30 minutes to finally find the user group and thus add it to the folder permissions. However, this is still a problem, because it should not take so long to change or edit folder permissions. Not to mention that in other cases I left it running for longer, and it never completed (so it doesn't find the users consistently either).

Comment: NTDS Diagnostic Logging can be turned on per DC, depending on the settings you choose, can log an ENORMOUS amount of information to the Directory Service event log. See here for how to enable: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314980. The changes are immediate, and since your issue is so unclear at this point, you may just try setting them all to "5", cliecking "Check Names", and setting them back to "0". THen get a cup of coffee and get inside AD's brain! I'm actually quite interested to see if you find a resolution.

Comment: One other thing you may try is NetMon to see if there is a network issue or if you see any hints in a capture. Who knows, maybe you have an MTU issue or something.

Comment: Are you sure that the client is resolving the domain's DNS name correctly? I experienced similar issues at a customer where the local.domain.com name of AD domain was also a public DNS record and the problematic clients did resolve the public ip instead of the local one.

Comment: @Marco I'm not sure why this question was bumped to the homepage, but this was "resolved" years ago. I mentioned in the comments what it took (waiting long enough), but I never really got a solid answer as to what was causing this. Since then the server seems to be running just fine.

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed it was from far 2013!

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the "Locations..." button and selecting "Entire Directory". If it starts working, then you have an LDAP issue. Selecting "Entire Directory" forces the Select dialog to use a GC port to execute the query. Selecting a specific domain will cause it to use an LDAP port.